# CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES GPU error

Tags: opencl, gpu

I am running multiple iterations of an OpenCL program, and after a few, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Read Result (-5)
CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES
```

when running this command

```
  err = clEnqueueReadBuffer( commands, d_c, CL_TRUE, 0,
                             sizeof(char) * result_size,
                               result_buffer, 0, NULL, NULL );

  checkErr(err,"Read Result");
```

The kernel allocates 3 global memory buffers, which I release

```
clReleaseMemObject(d_a);
clReleaseMemObject(d_b)
clReleaseMemObject(d_c);
clReleaseKernel(ko_smat);
```

But I also allocate local and private memory, the private memory is allocated in the kernel (char tmp_array) and local memory.
My kernel has definition:

```
__kernel void mmul(

        __global char* C,
        __global char* A,
        __global char* B,
        const int rA,
        const int rB,
        const int cC,
        __local char* local_mem)
```

The local memory is created in the kernel via

```
clSetKernelArg(ko_smat,6, sizeof(char) * local_mem_size, NULL);
```

I'm guessing that the out of memory error is caused by me failing to free either the private memory or the local memory, but I don't know how to?

Comment: Private and local memory have the lifetime of the kernel and are not *free*able.

Comment: that's what i thought, but what could explain then that i eventually get this error (after a number of iterations only?)

Comment: On nVIDIA platforms. An OUT_OF_RESOURCES error while reading a buffer that has been used to write data from a kernel indicates that the kernel did a SEG_FAULT while writing to that buffer. That is, it wrote to an address outside of the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't have enough reputation to comment, I have to use an answer.

To properly address your problem it will be helpful, if you post a working example of your code.

How much local memory do you actually allocate? It might very well possible that you allocate more than your device is capable of. If your "local_mem_size" variable is not fixed but calculated dynamically, find out the worst case scenario.
You can query how much local memory your device can provide, just call clGetDeviceInfo with CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE.

As DarkZeros already mentioned, CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES is an error that occurs on NVIDIA GPUs when addressing memory out of range. This can happen for both local and global memory.